# Where on Earth is this Win10 lock screen image from, with a stone town in a rock crevice?

Tags: where-on-earth, identify-this, photography

[image: Win10 lock screen image of small stone town built into a rock crevice]

I'm wondering where the place in the above photo is. I'd love to learn more about it! On my copy of Windows 10 Home there are links that share more info about photos, but on this PC with Windows 10 Pro there are no such links or additional info.

Comment: FYI: Those are commonly referred to as "cliff dwellings" in case you wanted to see if there were any close to you.  There are a number of different styles and sites throughout the US.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to Google's image search it is the **[Canyon de Chelly National Monument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canyon_de_Chelly_National_Monument)**.

Comment: That does look like it - thanks! And, thanks for 'reminding me how to fish' so to speak - should've JFGI